# Parse file JSON in titanium

Tags: android, json, titanium

I have a JSON file and want to parse value of variable second value in it(I want to get value "Open" in this file JSON..

{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
"menuitem": [{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},{"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},{"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
   }
   }}

I used code follow to parse but it's error:

```
    for(var i in itemList)
    {
    var thisItem = itemList[i];             
    var itemList1=JSON.parse(thisItem.popup);
    for(var j in itemList1)
    {
        var thisItem1=itemList1[0];
        label.text=thisItem1.value;
    }
    }
```

Can you help me.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how u can parse the json. working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/B5J5C/3/

The JSON text format is syntactically identical to the code for creating JavaScript objects.
​
If this is a JSON response from your server , There is no need to parse, you can access the properties of the object directly.

```
var jsonObject = {
   "menu":{
      "id":"file",
      "value":"File",
      "popup":{
         "menuitem":[
            {
               "value":"New",
               "onclick":"CreateNewDoc()"
            },
            {
               "value":"Open",
               "onclick":"OpenDoc()"
            },
            {
               "value":"Close",
               "onclick":"CloseDoc()"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
};

alert(jsonObject.menu.popup.menuitem[1].value);
```

If you are dealing with Json strings instead, use JSON.parse to retreive the Object , and then parse through it. working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/B5J5C/2/

```
    var jsonText = '{"menu": { "id": "file", "value": "File", "popup": { "menuitem": [{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},{"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},{"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"} ] } }}';

    alert(JSON.parse(jsonText).menu.popup.menuitem[1].value);

​
```

Comment: Sorry.I am a new user and i don't know accept the answer/up vote how to.Can you tell to me.